# Google Auth using social-auth-app-django on project(Django + React)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I have project with Djang + React and I need using Google OAuth2 to authenticate user login. Looks like `social-auth-app-django` is popular package to use for Django, and I had a search on how to use it.

But I could not find any example with React on frontend. I can see a lot of examples with a button implemented by Djang templates like this.

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">
    Login
 </a>
```

But what it should be pointing to with a React `Login` button? And should I pass Google OAuth2 Key or Google OAuth2 Secret from React to Django?

NEED HELP, thanks!

Comment: Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46476631/399435) answer: _While using `<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-plus' %}">Login</a>` for login, it translates to `/login/google-plus/`. This not only get's the acess_token but also creates a "social user" in your database._ May be that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google OAuth2 in react, `react-google-login` is a good package.

Comment: I need authenticate user login status on server side