# Django Google Login with React Frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, google-authentication

This question may be super simple but I've been googling for a while now and haven't found an exact solution.

I'm trying to implement a Google Login using React for the frontend and Django for the backend.

How exactly would I do this? I have seen solutions where a token is sent over to the backend which then retrieves the necessary information from the Google API and either creates or retrieves a user from the database based on the token. However, this seemed to be based on JWT and I was wondering if it is possible to implement the same with the simple Django Auth Token?

Maybe I'm just really blind but I really wasn't able to find a suitable solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if you can use anything other than React but there are many apps for django that handle Oauth https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/oauth/

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998707/10796680

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was actually working on this a few moments ago, after many fails in the past. It's quite a headache really trying to find a solution that works with React. I have however managed to easily setup google login on the React front end side with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login. This should be the first step you will need to take.

After that you will need to setup social login on the Django backend using django_allauth. Basically, the idea is once a user logs in via google or to be precise, clicks on the Login With Google button on the front end, a google access_token will be retrieved from Google and saved in local storage together with some other data. Only the access_token is of interest here. So you will then need to take this access_token and send it to the Django backend via a Rest API of a view that you will have setup. That will get the google user data saved in the database under social accounts, ultimately login them in the application. Everything from then on should continue as per your normal logins with email and username. That is if using JWT, a jwt token will be returned from the backend which you hopefully should be able to save in local storage. In my React app, I authenticate against this token, so as long as I have the token in local storage, a user is logged in.

Pratik Singh Chauhan does a good job explaining this in his Part 1 tutorial here -> https://medium.com/@pratique/social-login-with-react-and-django-i-c380fe8982e2 and Part 2 here -> https://medium.com/@pratique/social-login-with-react-and-django-ii-39b8aa20cd27

**UPDATE:** *June 2022*

Since Google is now moving to (GIS) Google Identity Services sign-in SDK, this method, although it works is now deprecated.

Here is a good link to help you setup react login with the new google GIS.

https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/issues/12#issuecomment-1131408898

There are 2 methods you can use depending on your workflow, implicit or authorization. To maintain a similar workflow that the above code achieved, implicit workflow is the one that can give you both access_token and refresh_token that you will send to your backend api.

Here is another link with sample code for both workflows.

https://react-oauth.vercel.app/

Note you will need to use **@react-oauth/google** to configure the Google workflows in your code.

Refer to this:

https://reactjsexample.com/google-oauth2-using-the-new-google-identity-services-sdk-for-react/

Comment: How do you handle refresh token? I got this working but my token expires after 1 minute...

Comment: Set the following in your settings.py with your desired time for expiration:

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
}

Answer (score 0):

hi i think what you need is this super useful article from google
[google tutorial on how to implement](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)
basically just add google-api-python-client to your requirements.txt
and the rest is very simple
you dont even need to download jwtpython

so what happens
is the request comes to django backend

google decodes the jwt and makes sure to verify it else wise it runs a error

than you get the ['sub'] of the info of the user which is the google id

so add to your user model a charfield(since number is even too big for bigInt)

now when a user comes in you add his email just like normal and you add his name and so on, but you set the password to a blank string which is safe since in django a hashed password "" is not the same as a raw password "" so no one can login to that account (but if you want just prevent logins using default logins to people that have a googleid)

than you add the google id to the user field (you leave it null for non google users)

and also if the google id already exists that you login that user intead of signing him up

heres how i have it setup in my [mug](https://github.com/MicheleAwada/mug) project (btw if you wanna visit the specific file it is in /frontend/myauth/views.py in the mug repo link i have above)

```
class GoogleAuth(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    token = data.get('credential')
    try:
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, google_requests.Request(), google_client_id)

        if not (idinfo["aud"] == google_client_id == data.get("clientId")):
            raise ValidationError("Invalid client ID.")
    except:
        # Invalid token
        return Response({"status": "invalid token"}, status=400)
    else:
        userid = str(idinfo['sub'])
        email = idinfo.get('email')
        name = idinfo.get("name")
        google_users_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="google_users")


        user = google_users_group.user_set.filter(google_id=userid)
        user_exists = user.exists()
        if user_exists:# login account
            user = user.first()
        else: # create account
            username = random_username_from_name(name)
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, name=name, password="",
                                            groups=[google_users_group], hash=False, google_id=userid)
            picture_url = idinfo.get("picture", None)
            if picture_url is not None:
                add_image_from_url(user, "avatar", picture_url)
        return return_user_data(user)
```

anyways its very simple
and i hope i can leviate any other new persons headache when trying to figure this out it literally took my months to find that golden google article

and obviously i wont go into the frontend cause its a piece of cake
all you need is this @react-oauth/google which is very well documented and allows for the beatiful one tap signup / login
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google)