# Django allauth + React google social login

Tags: reactjs, django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I have `django-allauth` working well with Google social login when I'm directly accessing the backend. I'm now wondering how to use this from (or replace with) my React frontend.

Originally my backend was FastAPI and with `fastapi-users` and it was working well enough with React. That is, in React I have a `useAuth` hook which in turn relies on `useContext`, while my React button would `GET` the `auth_url` from the backend's `/auth/google/authorize`, redirect me, use the `/auth/google/callback`, and ultimately store the token in a cookie.

With Django I now wonder what the general approach should be. Should I:

- Option A: have my React button take me to django-allauth's `/accounts/google/login`, where the user completes the login cycle and is ultimately redirected back to my React's `/profile`? The issue so far is that even though the backend google part seems to work, upon redirect React complains that the token is empty. For now this is not surprising since I'm not yet sending that token back to the frontend. But idk if to keep working on this approach or if instead I should...
- Option B: try to recreate the `/auth/google/authorize` and `/auth/google/callback` flow I had working with FastAPI but now using Django. Specifically I am using django-ninja and most tutorials use Django DRF, and although I can probably imitate the steps regardless, idk if to try this path if it's no longer necessary given the switch to django-allauth? Apparently I would have to send over the frontend's token to the backend, which I think goes against what I currently have working with django-allauth. Also, I'm seeing some mention (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784983/django-google-login-with-react-frontend) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998590/google-auth-using-social-auth-app-django-on-projectdjango-react/59998707#59998707)) of `react-google-login`, but maybe it is now deprecated or unnecessary?

Are these 2 equally valid workflows or is one preferable to the other? Is option A more secure? From my POV it feels like with option A I would be taking advantage of the already functional authentication but idk.