# How to use social auth app django with React.js frontend?

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm using Django on my backend, where I'm loging users with LinkedIn account. I've done everything following documentation, and it's working great. Now I want to use my views as API to my React.js project. How can I remake

```html
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}">Sign in with Linkedin</a>
```

as React button?

I found similar question
[Google Auth using social-auth-app-django on project(Django + React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998590/google-auth-using-social-auth-app-django-on-projectdjango-react)